# How to validate a request in class-validator if a property in payload doesn't match the dto Object?

Tags: nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

I am currently using nest.js for my project while Mongo acting as DB. How to validate invalid payload in the class-validator? Joi package has the inbuilt support for this

```
import { IsString, IsInt, IsOptional } from 'class-validator';

export class CreateMovieDto {
  @IsString()
  readonly title: string;

  @IsInt()
  readonly year: number;

  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  readonly plot: string;
}
```

My payload:

```
{
    "title": "Interstellar",
    "year": 2014,
    "director": "Christopher Nolan"
}
```

Here I've not mentioned **director** in the dto. But it is inserting automatically. I don't want to use **@Exclude()** by restricting named properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to just exclude unknown values during validation, you can use `whitelisting`.

> Even if your object is an instance of a validation class it can contain additional properties that are not defined. If you do not want to have such properties on your object, pass special flag to validate method.
>
> This will strip all properties that don't have any decorators
>
> https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#whitelisting

Since you are using NestJS, you can use `ValidationPipe` for this:

```
@UsePipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
        whitelist: true,
    }),
)
```

---

If you want to throw a validation error instead when an unknown value occurs, you can use `forbidNonWhitelisted`.

```
@UsePipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
        whitelist: true,
        forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
    }),
)
```